# filling missing or dead indexes of array without renumbering php

Tags: php, arrays

how can i fill the missing indexes as blank space, without renumbering the indexes of array.

```
**array (size=3)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string 'Man' (length=3)
  5 => string 'Mining' (length=6)**
```

for instance, how can i fill the blank spaces in the missing indexes by loop, may be foreach, or for loop.
desired output:

```
 **array (size=3)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string 'Man' (length=3)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
      5 => string 'Mining' (length=6)**
```

Comment: What is your end goal? It's kind of an odd thing to try to do it this way, it will just make most of your work with that array harder in the end.

Comment: actully its 2D array printing with empty vallues, thats y ..

Comment: So why add them to the array, just print them when you're doing output.

Comment: actully the requirment is of three rows, dts y @Jessica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<?php

$arr = array(0=>1,1=>2,10=>5); // Your array ...
$maxkey = array_search(max($arr),$arr); // Finding the highest key from your array (required to determine the iterations)

for($i=0;$i<$maxkey;$i++)
{
if(!array_key_exists($i,$arr)) // if key exists.. ignore .. else fill the element with space..
{
$arr[$i]='';
}
}
ksort($arr);// sorts the array using keys..
var_dump($arr);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
   if(!isset($array[$i]){
      $array[$i] = '';
   }
}
```

It's very simple to do, but you should probably explore why you're trying to do this, and find a better solution.

Comment: mu goal is, to print the 2d array without changing indexes as column names of table, where i required blank cells also in first two rows

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_pad](http://php.net/array_pad)

```
$a1 = array(0 => '', 1 => 'Man', 5 => 'Mining'); 
$a2 = array_pad(array(), max(array_keys($a1)), ''); 
$a = $a1 + $a2;
```

Comment: sounds cool, but doesnt arrange the indexes in acending order, or u can say it adds the indexes at the end of array.